# Bookshelf.js many-to-many relations

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js

I’m struggling to figure out how to do deep relations with Bookshelf.js and postgres.

Say I have three models, `User`, `Org` and `UserRole` … `User` and `Org` have a many-to-many relationship. `UserRole` and `User` is many-to-many through `Org`. Where I’m struggling conceptually is how to accomplish: `User 1` belongs to `Org A` and `Org B`; `User 1` should be an `Admin` role in `Org A`, but not in `Org B`

I've not been able to find any examples or hints in the bookshelf.js documentation or interwebs, and the documentation always refer to joining a table in the singular, not tables. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given the above, the relations are:

- "User" `belongsToMany` "Org"
- "User" `hasMany` "UserRole"
- "Org" `belongsToMany` "User"
- "Org" `hasMany` "UserRole"
- "UserRole" `belongsTo` "Org"
- "UserRole" `belongsTo` "User"

And here's how to load "UserRoles" for a "User" by "Org":

```
UserRole.forge({
    name: 'Admin',
    user_id: 1,
    org_id: 2
})
.save()
.then(function () {
    User.forge({ id: 1 }).fetch().then(function (user) {
        user.user_roles().query({ where: { org_id: 2 }}).fetch().then(function (user_roles) {
            console.log('user_roles: %j', user_roles);
        }),
    });
});
```